# Brownie Contract not being grabbed - `Unknown contract address`

Tags: python, ethereum, brownie

I'm following along with the [brownie documentation](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html?highlight=contract#contract-and-projectcontract), and have come across this:

> classbrownie.network.contract.Contract(address_or_alias, owner=None)
> A deployed contract that is not part of a Brownie project.

> address_or_alias: Address of the contract.
> owner: An optional Account instance. If given, transactions to the contract are > sent broadcasted from this account by default.

```
>>> from brownie import Contract
>>> Contract("0x79447c97b6543F6eFBC91613C655977806CB18b0")
<Token Contract object '0x79447c97b6543F6eFBC91613C655977806CB18b0'>
```

However, if I take the same code and put it into a script called `call.py` I get an error:

```
brownie run scripts/call.py --network mainnet
```

```
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

MultiCallProject is the active project.
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 53, in run
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 149, in _import_from_path
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "./scripts/multi-call.py", line 4, in <module>
    addr_provider = Contract("0x79447c97b6543F6eFBC91613C655977806CB18b0")
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 946, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f"Unknown contract address: '{address}'")
ValueError: Unknown contract address: '0x79447c97b6543F6eFBC91613C655977806CB18b0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have it in your main function.

Change

```py
contract = Contract("0x79447c97b6543F6eFBC91613C655977806CB18b0")
```

to

```py
def main():
    contract = Contract("0x0000000022D53366457F9d5E68Ec105046FC4383")
    print("ko")
```

And it'll pull the contract in.